# Creating a new ADO extension via tutorial. How to test?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm completely new to creating an ADO extension, so please bear with me.

I've created a new ADO extension by following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops

It has been packaged and installed into my org, but I'm not sure how to test if it works. I feel like they've left off some details to make this process a bit more beginner friendly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Try your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops#try-your-extension): Your extension contributed a view named "My Hub" to the project-level Code area. Let's navigate to it.

Steps: Open project->Repo->click the tab My Hub

Result:

[image]

Comment: I see it! Thank you so much. In the debugging part, I' m aware that the manifest is the vss-extension.json and I am supposed to add "baseUri". How does one go about running the extension on a localhost? Apologize if this is a silly question. I'm completely new to developing and integrating ADO extensions.